# Scala weird behavior for type conversion in generic function

Tags: scala, reflection, casting, type-erasure

Could anyone explain why that happens?

```
scala> def as[T](v: Any) = Try(v.asInstanceOf[T])
as: [T](v: Any)scala.util.Try[T]

scala> as[Int]("Hello")
res0: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(Hello)

scala> res0.map(_ + 1)
res1: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer)
```

It's not about boxing because you could use your own type instead of `Int` and it behaves the same way.

Doesn't seem to be about by-name parameter either, because you could replace `Try` with `Option` and it will be the same.

I'm guessing it's about erasure, but maybe somebody could give a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any@asInstanceOf[T0]:T0):

> Note that the success of a cast at runtime is modulo Scala's erasure semantics. Therefore the expression `1.asInstanceOf[String]` will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, while the expression `List(1).asInstanceOf[List[String]]` will not. In the latter example, because the type argument is erased as part of compilation it is not possible to check whether the contents of the list are of the requested type.

So, because `T` is erased, `Try(v.asInstanceOf[T])` will not immediately throw a `ClassCastException`, because as far as the JVM knows, you have a `Try[Any]`. But as soon as you try to treat the contained type like an `Int`, you trigger the exception.